# How does measuring amps on a multimeter work?

Tags: multimeter, amperage

When I measure the amperage coming from two AA batteries to an LED, these are my results:

```
On the 2m setting: .002
On the 20m/10A setting: 0.02
On the 200m setting: 00.2
```

I have one wire in the COM port, and one in the 10A port. Does this mean that my that my LED is drawing 20mA? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are shorting out the ammeter.  Give us a schematic of how everything is hooked together.

Comment: Those values are effectively noise. Read the DMM specs.

Comment: If your lead is connected to 10A input, only the 10A setting in the mulitmeter will give you any results. Use the other positive input lead of the multimeter and place the multimeter so that the current flows *through* the multimeter, e.g. you must connect the multimeter between the led and the battery, not across the LED or the battery.

Comment: it sounds like that's exactly what that means, and most signal LEDs are indeed ~20ma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 10 Amp jack, you should only use the 10 Amp range.

On the 10 Amp range, you read 0.02 Amp, or 20 mA.

Answer (score 0):

If your lead is connected to 10A input, only the 10A setting in the multimeter will give you any results.

Use the COM port and the other positive input port (the one that shows V/mA/Ohm) of the multimeter and place the multimeter so that the current flows *through* the multimeter, e.g. you must connect the multimeter between the led and the battery, not across the LED or the battery.